# Github SSH Permission denied to deploy key

Tags: git, ssh

I created a fresh repo, was able to clone with SSH and commit and everything. But when I try to push I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Permission to Ronin11/MealPlanr.git denied to deploy key
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

Using:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I was able to verify that my ssh key is working. I have no idea what happened. This was just working the other day. I haven't touched these settings in months.
All this was using the terminal on Mac.

Help!

Comment: Remove all other identities from your keyring: `ssh-add -D`, re-add the key and try again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mentioned you were using OSX. If you're on 10.12.2+ it may be a problem with your ssh config. Github's documentation has a note about that.

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Specifically they say add the following to `~/.ssh/config`

`Host *
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Hope this helps

Comment: Note that this file, config, might not be in the .ssh/ directory. Don't let that throw you: you will need this file. Once it is added with the correct configuration details, the push relationship will work.

Comment: Just want to say, it's 2024 and this answer is still helping folks.

Answer (score 14):

It's possible that your key is **already linked to one repo**.

Try to use `ssh -T -ai ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com`
to find the concerned repo.

All details here
https://help.github.com/en/articles/error-key-already-in-use

Comment: The output will be like:
$ ssh -T -ai /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com; 
Hi <github-username>/<repo-name>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Answer (score 12):

For me the following always works for GitHub push:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`; ssh-add your_key; git push
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1:

`ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa; your_git command'`

In this case, you have to repeat the above command by appending your git command each time. I would not recommend this.

Solution 2:

```
ssh-add -D
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

These two commands will remove ad add the SSH keys for a single sign-on.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another might be that your id_rsa private key file has too broad of permissions, e.g. `0644`, and the error is getting buried.

Restrict the perms:

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

**Note**: you'll need to re-add the key to ssh-agent

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And test again:

```
ssh -T -ai ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I already had a key defined specifically for github.com in my ~/.ssh/config file.  I erroneously added a public key that *was not* the one I had in the config file.  Without using the verbose option, you'll get a message everything is fine.  With verbose option `(ssh -vT git@github.com)`, the output will start providing clues regarding line numbers like

`debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 66: Applying options for github.com`

Where my ~/.ssh/config file has this in it

`Host github github.com`
`HostName github.com`
`etc`

It seems obvious after the fact, but.. ensure you're using the correct public key that corresponds to any specific entries for gihub listed in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

The probable  answer to your issue is that you are using a `deploy key` which usually only has read access. If it did have write access at one stage, perhaps someone has changed it back to read only.

Answer (score 0):

For mac users!

as #sashaboulouds has mentioned  earlier, when you run this code in ur terminal

$  *ssh -T -ai ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com*

You will get a message like this

"Hi yourName ! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."

if you see any project name next to your user name (like userName/repositoryName , you definitely used ur public ssh key to a single repo.

The solution is

- copy your public key from your terminal/command line by running

$ *cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub*

and go to your github account

- under your “repositoryName” repo

  - delete the already attached public key
- under your GitHub username account setting

  - click on  SSH and GPG keys
  - add a new SSH key
  - fill in the title and paste the public key in the key area provided

**Test it**

run
$ *ssh -T -ai ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com*

if you see the message with your GitHub account only. you have successfully assigned the public to your account as a whole.