# Can pull for Git repo but not push

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I just generated an SSH key and added it to my ssh-agent in a Linux Mint terminal.  I then copied the content of the `.pub` file and pasted into the GitHub user-wide SSH key box.  I call `git pull` and it works.  I call `add` and `commit` and everything seems fine.

But then I call `git push -u origin main` and I get

```
ERROR: Permission to name/repo.git denied to deploy key
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 4):

When you uploaded the public key you generated to GitHub, you put it in the per-repository deploy key box.  Deploy keys are SSH keys designed to operate on a single repository, and they are read-only by default.  You have to check the box when you add the public key if you want the key to be read-write.  That's because in many cases, deploy keys are used only to deploy code, and so it's better not to grant them access they don't need.  They can also be used for other machine operations, though, so write access is available.

Since you've already uploaded it, you'll have to delete the deploy key from GitHub and re-add it, since there's no way to change the settings for an existing key.  When you re-add it, check the checkbox that says, “Allow write access.”

If you had intended this to work for your entire user account instead of just this particular repository, then you'll need to remove the deploy key entry and upload it instead in [your user settings](https://github.com/settings/keys).  You have to remove the deploy key entry first because the same key can only be used for one purpose, and the key identifies the actor (user or deploy key) and permissions.

Comment: I didn't describe this accurately because I didn't know there was a way to give each repo a deploy key.  Sorry about that. What I really did at the beginning was add this to the user settings.  But based on what you said, I tried deleting it and adding it instead to the specific repo.  It still didn't work.  And when I put it back in the user settings, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then please edit your question to show the error message you receive when you use it as a user key.  The message you're receiving clearly says it's a deploy key, and if you continue to see that message, that means it isn't being used as a user key.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  It is the message I get even when I have the key as a user key.  So I'm not sure why it's mentioning a deploy key.

Comment: It's likely that you're not using the key you think you're using.  If you have multiple keys you're using with GitHub, see [the Git FAQ entry](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#multiple-accounts-ssh) about how to make that work properly.

Comment: Hm, I tried all this stuff in every way I can think of.  I even deleted the repo, created a new key, updated the `config` file with everything I can find that is recommended to put into it, put the new key in the user settings, cloned the repo.  Still it keeps giving a message about a deploy key, but the repo has no deploy key.

Answer (score -1):

```
Specifically they say add the following to ~/.ssh/config

Host *
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43054414/6521970